# vaadin's Invient chart max data size

Tags: java, javascript, highcharts, vaadin

Using invient charts add-on for vaadin and trying to display about 8000 points, but this doesn't seem to work.

In the javascript console I'm also getting something like :

> Error: Problem parsing d="0" highcharts.js:9 
>   Error: Problem parsing d="0.006785371411752283" highcharts.js:9 
>   Error: Problem parsing d="0.01772129077110096" highcharts.js:9
>   Error: Problem parsing d="0.9987513982081351" highcharts.js:9

even though I am not sending those points .... don't know where they come from.
The above errors are logged even if I render a small number of points - but in this case the chart will be displayed.

Does anyone know of limitations on the number of displayed points ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase turbothreshold parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold